# error when i cancel an order

Tags: magento2, sales-order

i don't know why but for some time, When in cancel an order, I get this error : [image]

when i want block the order, i get the same message.

However **when I cancel from massAction, it's work**.
Anyone have an idea?

Hoping you can help me.

Comment: Is there any error log?

Comment: I found nothing in the logs.it's very strange!!

Comment: Should use Inspect Browser and check the response from the network?

Comment: i found nothing in inspect browser too

Answer (score 0):

You're being direct to a HTTPS page, but your SSL setup is invalid. Either disable all options and URLs relating to HTTPS in your Magento configuration, or setup a valid certificate.

Comment: My certificate is valid since on all the other pages it works, why only on this one?

Comment: Have you tried another browser? From what I could find on Google, it suggests it might be a session issue.

Comment: yes, i tried with Firefox and chrome.Why it would be a session issue?

Comment: with Chrome, i get this error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540187/magento-website-suddenly-has-no-data-received-error-code-err-empty-response seems to be a similar issue.

Comment: Have you checked your web server logs? Not the magento ones, but the server itselfs' logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50439/discussion-between-eamonn-hayden-and-strauss).